# aaa_helper.rb is automatically included in aaa_controller.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

I have the following question: typing `rails new generate controller Comments` rails generates a controller file named comments_controller.rb and a file named comments_helpers.rb, now the question is: the module in the comments_helpers file is automatically included in my CommentsController class or not?

Answer (score 1):

`comments_helper.rb` will be included in the `CommentsController`'s *views*, not the controller actions itself.

You can define a method in `CommentsController` that's also accessible to views with the `helper_method` method by putting it in your controller:

```
def super_useful_helper_method
   ...
end

helper_method :super_useful_helper_method
```